# How to get the json object names dynamically in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have the below json sample and i would like to get the object names dynamically without passing as string.

```
{
    "John": {
        "Age": "22",
        "status": "married"
    },
    "Ross": {
        "Age": "34",
        "status": "divorced"
    }
}
```

I want to get keys John and Ross. I tried with

```
JSONObject parse = JSON.parseObject("");
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parse.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

but the above code gives all the keys inside. i only want the parent keys.

Comment: Then use `parse.keySet()`. You want *keys*, not *entries*.

Answer (score 0):

you can change `parse.entrySet()` to `parse.keySet()` to get the desire result.

```
JSONObject parse = JSON.parseObject("");
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parse.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the use of fastjson. Use `keySet` instead.

```
JSONObject parse = JSON.parseObject("");
for (String entry : parse.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

This will print:

```
John
Ross
```

Tested with:

```
String s = "{\"John\":{\"Age\":\"22\",\"status\":\"married\"},\"Ross\":{\"Age\":\"34\",\"status\":\"divorced\"}}";

JSONObject parse = JSON.parseObject(s);
for (String entry : parse.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```